# Calculate Euclidean Distance

Tags: matlab

I have 200 face image (32x32) where i reshape it into matrix data

> Face = 200 x 1024  (200 is the face sample, 1024 is one face image
>   vectorize into 1 line)
>
> Facemean = 1 x 1024 (mean of the image)

the euclidean distance equation 1 use will be :

```
 distance = sqrt ( (Face(1,1)-Facemean(1,1)^2 + (Face(1,2)-Facemean(1,2)^2  + . . . + (Face(200,1024)-Facemean(1,1024)^2 );
```

since using the equation above will be very long, so i would like to ask if there is any other way to calculate it?

The result i expected is 1 x 1 matrix value

Answer (score 0):

More elegant answer (from the comment below):

```
FacemeanMatrix = repmat( Facemean, [200, 1])
distance = sqrt( sum( ( Face(:)-FacemeanMatrix(:) ).^2 ))
```

---

*Previous answer*

You can write it as vectors:

```
dissqr = 0
% for each colum, calculate the square difference and sum all the lines
for i =1:200
  dissqr = dissqr + sum( (Face(i,:)-(Facemean(:,i).'))^2 )
end

distance = sqrt( dissqr )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it really help me. A little correction for Facemean(:,i).

Comment: i try to use matrix 5x5 and use the manual calculation `distance = sqrt ( (Face(1,1)-Facemean(1,1)^2 + (Face(1,2)-Facemean(1,2)^2  + . . . + (Face(5,5)-Facemean(1,5)^2 )` , it seem the result is quite different from both answer.

Comment: Does it change the result if you transpose `Facemean` (by adding `.'`) `(Facemean(:,i).'`  in the loop version ? Or replace the vector Facemean by a matrix containing the vector in each column (see updated answer) ?

Comment: Should probably test speed on possible solutions. Formats like `Face(i,:)` can be really slow. `Face(:)` may be fine -- a claim better if tested. Aside, why do you have `( Face(:)-FacemeanMatrix(:) )^2` instead of `( Face(:)-FacemeanMatrix(:) ).^2`?

Comment: i have add the transpose in the loop version but the result still quite different with the manual one. Also i forget to tell you about `.^2` as the Argyll said and i have implement it.

Comment: find out the FacemeanMatrix work with a little correction on `FacemeanMatrix = repmat( Facemean, [200, 1])`